# Is there a set type that preserves insertion order?

Tags: rust

Is there a type that preserves insertion order (think `Vec`) but only tracks unique values (think `HashSet`)? I want to avoid using `Vec` because I would first need to check if the value exists in it before insertion.

Comment: Did you see [linked-hash-map](https://crates.io/crates/linked-hash-map) crate? Maybe you can create a wrap with `V = ()`.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/30243100/155423 as sets are just maps without a value.

Comment: If the only change you need is adding elements and the elements are copyable, you could simply use both a set and a vector, using the set for the duplicate checks and the vector to store the elements in-order.

Comment: @CodesInChaos can you show what the code would look like

Comment: Which operation will be more used? Insert or remove?

Comment: About equal @malbarbo

Comment: @Tshepang The Rust equivalent of [this C# code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cf8c67145f7d508aae123d41de59fa12). For Copy types this should have a direct equivalent in Rust. But since you clarified that you don't just need to add elements but also remove them, this approach won't work for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`linked_hash_set`](https://crates.io/crates/linked_hash_set) crate is now available. It's based on the 
`linked-hash-map` crate mirroring the std `HashSet` API as closely as possible.

```
extern crate linked_hash_set;
use linked_hash_set::LinkedHashSet;

let mut set = LinkedHashSet::new();
set.insert(234);
set.insert(123);
set.insert(345);
set.insert(123);

assert_eq!(set.into_iter().collect::<Vec<_>>(), vec![234, 345, 123]);
```

Comment: I was disappointed to see it didn't implement retain() and I can't derive Deserialize for it. Just FYI.

Comment: `linked-hash-map` does not implement `retain` which would be the first step for that. For serialization the optional "serde" dependency/feature is available.

Comment: It is worth noting that when removal is not a frequently expected operation, [IndexSet](https://docs.rs/indexmap/latest/indexmap/set/struct.IndexSet.html) is a more appropriate choice giving better performance.

Answer (score 5):

Updating answers since `linked-hash-map` is in maintenance mode (see [github commit](https://github.com/contain-rs/linked-hash-map/commit/df66adc2ebb2fc7b81101de08faa44260920a25c))

---

The most popular github crates in September 2021:

- [indexmap](https://github.com/bluss/indexmap) which provide direct implementation of `IndexSet`.
- [array_tool](https://github.com/danielpclark/array_tool) which provide helper to build a vector set data structure with few lines of code.

Answer (score 4):

The [`linked-hash-map`](https://crates.io/crates/linked-hash-map) crate provides a hash map that holds key-value insertion order. We can create a set wrapper for this hash map using `()` as values ([`std::collections::HashSet`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/std/up/src/libstd/collections/hash/set.rs.html#105-107) is implemented this way):

```
extern crate linked_hash_map;

use linked_hash_map::*;
use std::collections::hash_map::RandomState;
use std::hash::{BuildHasher, Hash};
use std::borrow::Borrow;

fn main() {
    let mut s = LinkedHashSet::new();
    s.insert(5);
    s.insert(3);
    s.insert(7);
    s.insert(1);
    assert_eq!(vec![5, 3, 7, 1], s.iter().cloned().collect::<Vec<_>>());
    s.remove(&7);
    assert_eq!(vec![5, 3, 1], s.iter().cloned().collect::<Vec<_>>());
    s.remove(&5);
    assert_eq!(vec![3, 1], s.iter().cloned().collect::<Vec<_>>());
}

pub struct LinkedHashSet<K, S = RandomState>(LinkedHashMap<K, (), S>);

impl<K: Hash + Eq> LinkedHashSet<K> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        LinkedHashSet(LinkedHashMap::new())
    }
}

impl<K: Hash + Eq, S: BuildHasher> LinkedHashSet<K, S> {
    pub fn insert(&mut self, k: K) -> Option<()> {
        self.0.insert(k, ())
    }

    pub fn contains<Q: ?Sized>(&self, k: &Q) -> bool
        where K: Borrow<Q>,
              Q: Eq + Hash
    {
        self.0.contains_key(k)
    }

    pub fn remove<Q: ?Sized>(&mut self, k: &Q) -> Option<()>
        where K: Borrow<Q>,
              Q: Eq + Hash
    {
        self.0.remove(k)
    }

    pub fn iter(&self) -> Keys<K, ()> {
        self.0.keys()
    }
}
```

You can implement other methods. See `LinkedHashMap` [docs](http://contain-rs.github.io/linked-hash-map/linked_hash_map/).

Answer (score 0):

RiteLinked provides more up to date versions of LinkedHashMap & LinkedHashSet in Rust. You can easily use it on std or no_std environment. You can use it instead of linked-hash-map and linked_hash_set.

- https://github.com/ritedb/ritelinked
- https://crates.io/crates/ritelinked